# c++ syntax in understanding rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I was reading a blog about c++11 rvalue references by [Thomas Becker](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html), and the following syntax near the bottom of the page really confuses me.

```
  int& foo();
  foo() = 42; // ok, foo() is an lvalue
```

What exactly is `foo`? A function pointer that returns a `int`; an object?

If a function object, how can you assign a value to it, and why is `foo` a lvalue?

Comment: `foo` is not an `lvalue` the value that returns though is.

Comment: @40two `foo` as an id-expression is an lvalue.

Comment: @40two To be even more precise, the expression `foo()` is an lvalue. Contrary to their name, value categories categorize *expressions*, not values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` is a function with return type `int&`. The line

```
int& foo();
```

simply declares the function, but does not define it.

When `foo` is called, the result is an lvalue of type `int`. Therefore you can assign to it: `foo() = 42;`

Answer (score 5):

`int& foo();` declares a function `foo` that takes no arguments and returns a reference to an `int`. For example,

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 0;
int& foo();

int main()
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    foo() = 42;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int& foo() { return a; }
```

Output:

```
0
42
```

Answer (score 0):

Every function has at least one return expression. Let's look at function calling using the following incomplete, simplified description :

Assume your function signature is `T f();`, with one return expression `return e;`. For the sake simplicity, lets also assume that `e` and `T` have the same type after removing [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) and [`const`-ness](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv). In this situation, you can go to your function call location and replace the call `f()` with `(T)e`, to understand what's going on.

```
int& f(){....; return e;}

.
.
.

f() = 5;
```

becomes

```
(int&)e = 5;
```

Of course, if converting `e` to an lvalue reference(`int&`) was invalid, the compiler will throw an error.